# Angular Material Date Picker adding horizontal line

Tags: javascript, angular

When I copy the DatePicker example from the Angular Material website it's adding an extra horizontal line to the bottom of it and I can't figure out why.

Here's the example:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And here's a screenshot:

[image: DatePicker]

Comment: This code is not adding any extra line. Could you post the code, where you are using datepicker ?

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was some bootstrap thing that I had to override in CSS.

Comment: @MikeA. What was your solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is because you are using the angular material and also the cdn of materialize or materialize style.
you could delete this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

and the line of the datepicker will be ok, and then, you could use other grid system for de rows and cols.
for example: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Answer (score 0):

I am just leaving this here in case someone else makes the same mistake I did. In my case I accidentally copy and pasted the date picker code inside an existing `mat-form-field`. I didn't notice it at first because of all the markup.

I had it like this and removing the outer `mat-form-field` fixed it for me:

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="endDate" #endDate="ngModel" [matDatepicker]="picker1">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-form-field>
```